# Git add interactive new file

Tags: git, git-add

Is there any way when I am adding new files to my project to make them be picked up by

```
git add -i
```

If I make changes to an existing file, then that is ok. But creating a new file it is marked as untracked and `git add -i` does not pick it up.

Comment: Hi...Can you try to use `git add --all` or `git add--interactive` ?

Answer (score 3):

When you are in the interactive session of "git add -i" you can use the option number 4 to add  untracked files

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `git add .` and `git add -i` does not stage all changes whether tracked or untracked. You could try using `git gui` to choose which files to stage if you have it installed.